# How to de-escalate a heated argument with my undergrad advisor?

Tags: research-undergraduate

The original issue is explained in detail
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4387687/divisibility-of-ideals/4387727#4387727) - the gist of that is that the advisor used the "I have a PhD and you are a puny undergrad" line on me while arguing about the substance of my thesis. We are both emotional people, and the discussion got quite heated.

I have since tried to change the advisor, but our department rejected my attempt. I suspect this is because the head of the department is a close friend to that doctor, so I'm planning to write a complaint about it to the dean of science. What would be a good way to navigate this situation?

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: This seems like a fine rant! What else have you got for us?

Comment: We can't answer your question if you don't have any.

Comment: I presume the question is: “How do I effectively file a complaint against the very poor behavior of this doctor?”.

Comment: (Or otherwise navigate to a successful outcome, perhaps by finding a ombudsman or some other resource)

Comment: @zachHunter Yesss thank you for articulating better than I could ever have

Comment: I have edited it to the best of my ability. Please review it and, if possible, add a country tag - local cultural norms might be relevant. More importantly, please outline your desired outcome space: how long until your graduation, do you want to change advisor, do you consider mending the existing relationship at least to the point of graduating under your current one etc.

Comment: I suggest to edit the question "how to **De**-escalate [...]" ... when you are the weakest side, a conflict will lead to a loss.

Comment: Your link is to a Math Overflow answer, not something that explains the original issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, your advisor

- is a complete jerk
- could stand to read an introductory book on algebraic number theory.

Personally, I wouldn't try to "win this fight"; instead, I'd recommend attempting to de-escalate to the extent possible and focusing on your own career goals. You might start by seeking out any faculty member in the department whom you know and trust, and asking them how to proceed.

Best of luck.